# Requests with proxy and thread

Tags: python, multithreading, proxy, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to check huge proxies lists. In order to do that, I'm using threads. I really need these threads because I'm using the same code structure latter, in order to make many requests on a website where I'm doing 1 thread = 1 IP.

So my sorting code is:

```
def proxyList(proxies, nbThread):
    with open('proxyList.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('')
        f.close()
    proxies = list(set(proxies))
    prox = []
    lenS = len(proxies)
    pas = int(lenS/nbThread)
    subSeq = [proxies[i*pas:(i+1)*pas] for i in range(nbThread)]
    subSeq[nbThread-1]+=proxies[nbThread*pas:]
    threads = [0 for i in range(nbThread)]

    for i in range(nbThread):
        threads[i] = proxy(subSeq[i], )
    for i in range(nbThread):
        threads[i].start();
    for i in range(nbThread):
        threads[i].join();

    return list(set(prox))

class proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, proxies):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.proxies = proxies

    def run(self):
        k=0
        prox = []
        for proxy in self.proxies:
            k+=1
            try:
                requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", timeout=15, proxies={"https":str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0])})
                try:
                    requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", timeout=15, proxies={"https":str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0])})
                    prox+=[str(proxy)]
                    print("Bon proxy : " + str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0]))
                    with open('proxyList.txt', 'a') as f:
                        f.writelines(str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0])+'\n');
                        f.close()
                except:
                    t = "a"
            except:
                print("Mauvais proxy : "+ str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0]))
                print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("Terminé: "+str(k), prox)
```

It works, but I don't always have the same output results, it's highly related to the number of threads I set.

Do you guys have an idea, I've seen that maybe requests is not the best choice here but I really need my threads with my proxies.

Thanks,
Djokx

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that request is the best way. Here is the discussion below;

https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705

But I have tried to make some improvement on your code, decreased for loops which has been doing same job and prevented to call "get" method twice.

Hope it helps

```
def proxyList(proxies, nbThread):
    with open('proxyList.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('')
        f.close()
    proxies = list(set(proxies))
    prox = []
    lenS = len(proxies)
    pas = int(lenS/nbThread)
    subSeq = [proxies[i*pas:(i+1)*pas] for i in range(nbThread)]
    subSeq[nbThread-1]+=proxies[nbThread*pas:]
    threads = [0 for i in range(nbThread)]

    for i in range(nbThread):
        threads[i] = proxy(subSeq[i], )
        threads[i].start()
        threads[i].join()

    return list(set(prox))

class proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, proxies):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.proxies = proxies

    def run(self):
        k=0
        prox = []
        for proxy in self.proxies:
            k+=1
            try:
                s = requests.Session()
                try:
                    s.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", timeout=15, proxies={"https":str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0])})
                    prox+=[str(proxy)]
                    print("Bon proxy : " + str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0]))
                    with open('proxyList.txt', 'a') as f:
                        f.writelines(str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0])+'\n');
                        f.close()
                except:
                    t = "a"
            except:
                print("Mauvais proxy : "+ str(re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+', proxy)[0]))
                print(sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("Terminé: "+str(k), prox)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I'm tryng to run proxyList twice, with the same parameters, the results are pretty different between the two. Do you know why ?

Thanks

Comment: Btw, thanks for the code improvements mate ! :)
But it seems that if i'm doing:

    for i in range(nbThread):
        threads[i] = proxy(subSeq[i], )
        threads[i].start()
        threads[i].join()

It will wait for the first thread to be stopped to start the second one, no ? I've try with that, it's much much slower !

Comment: I thought you dont need to wait to finish every for loop. So, I recommended to insert start and join in one loop. Thats why you should wait less, but is there any multithreading not exist? If so, you are right. It is going to take a bigger delay.

Ultimately can you clarify what kind of differences at results?